# Rails 3 Drag and drop between folders

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tree structure in my application like folders when I click on folders on same page its going to show all files under that folder
with an ajax call.

Folders has many files.

So now my problem is, I want to drag file from one folder to another folder. So that if files folder_id which I am dragging is 1, when I drop it to Folder 2, in back end it should update as folder_id= 2

I am not getting any idea to do this,

1. How can I enable user to drag file and drop in any folders
2. Once he dragged and dropped, how should I update in back end

Comment: Any number of ways, from rolling your own solution to a dozen different JS libraries. There is no *right* solution, and this is too general a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Ext. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/tree/reorder.html

The way you update your back end is by a simple Ajax call that passes the current state of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will do this quite well.  Check out these two pages -

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: To send the folder change to the server, you'll probably want to do an ajax call on the "drop" event of droppable.